# React Native Expo Video av-expo -- Directly play as fullscreen

Tags: react-native, video, expo, fullscreen

I'm trying to do this by react-native using the av-expo video.

What I'm trying to do is to launch the video directly in full screen without going through the "Video" stack (without the double loading of the MediaPlayerScreen stack + the native fullScreen stack).

If the user mutes the full screen by the native fullScreen output button, then we go back directly to a stack

The idea is to use only the native fullscreen stack to display the video. Is this possible?

I don't know if I'm clear, if it can help to understand, here is the code of my MediaPlayerScreen component

```js
export class MediaPlayerScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        //header: null,
        headerTitle: '',
        headerTransparent: false,
        headerTintColor: 'white',
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.AG = AG.instance
        this.filePath =
            this.AG.getFilePath() + props.navigation.state.params.file
        this.windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width
        this.windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height
    }
    //
    onPlaybackStatusUpdate = (playbackStatus) => {
        if (playbackStatus.didJustFinish) {
            this.props.navigation.goBack()
        }
    }
    //
    _handleVideoRef = async (component) => {
        const playbackObject = component
        if (playbackObject) {
            await playbackObject.loadAsync({
                uri: this.filePath,
                shouldPlay: false,
                posterSource: this.poster,
            })
            // todo: Trigger fullScreen without videoStack loading
            //playbackObject.presentFullscreenPlayer();
            playbackObject.playAsync()
            //playbackObject.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(this.onPlaybackStatusUpdate);
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.LANDSCAPE)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        //playbackObject.dismissFullscreenPlayer();
        //this.props.navigation.goBack();
        ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(
            ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.PORTRAIT_UP
        )
    }
    
    onFullscreenUpdate = ({ fullscreenUpdate, status }) => {
        console.log(fullscreenUpdate, status)
        switch (fullscreenUpdate) {
            case Video.FULLSCREEN_UPDATE_PLAYER_WILL_PRESENT:
                console.log(' the fullscreen player is about to present')
                break
            case Video.FULLSCREEN_UPDATE_PLAYER_DID_PRESENT:
                console.log('the fullscreen player just finished presenting')
                break
            case Video.FULLSCREEN_UPDATE_PLAYER_WILL_DISMISS:
                console.log('the fullscreen player is about to dismiss')
                break
            case Video.FULLSCREEN_UPDATE_PLAYER_DID_DISMISS:
                console.log('the fullscreen player just finished dismissing')
        }
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <Video
                    ref={this._handleVideoRef}
                    useNativeControls
                    rate={1.0}
                    resizeMode="contain"
                    onPlaybackStatusUpdate={(playbackStatus) =>
                        this.onPlaybackStatusUpdate(playbackStatus)
                    }
                    onFullscreenUpdate={this.onFullscreenUpdate}
                    style={{
                        width: this.windowHeight,
                        height: this.windowWidth,
                    }}
                />
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help,

Meums/

Answer (score 1):

hey if I am not getting you wrong you want to load the player fullscreen by default.you can follow this approach:

```
      const videoRef = useRef(null);
      <Video
       ref={videoRef}
       useNativeControls={false}
       style={styles.container}
       isLooping
       source={{
         uri: videoUri,
       }}
       onLoad={()=>{
       videoRef?.current?.presentFullscreenPlayer();
        }
       resizeMode="contain"
       onPlaybackStatusUpdate={(status) => setStatus(() => status)}
       />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Basically, one small workaround would be to render Video component inside the View where styling of that View would have both height and width set to 1 (it will not be visible). Good place for that is bottom tab bar.
2. You also need to set Video ref.

```
 <View
      style={{
        height :1,
        width: 1,        
      }}
     <Video
       ref={videoRef}
...
```

Then, you can use this useEffect:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true
    if (!id) return;

    (async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetchVideUrl(id);
        if (response && isMounted) {          
            setSrc(response.url);                    
              const loaded = await videoRef.current?.loadAsync({ uri: response.url });
              const status = await videoRef.current?.playAsync();              
              await videoRef.current?.presentFullscreenPlayer();
          
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    })();

    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, [id]);
```

so when video would be loaded, it will start in the fullscreen mode (or it will look like that).

Note: If you are using bottom sheet, modals, etc. you still can use same approach - render Video component somewhere where it will not be visible, and then start fullscreen using Video's ref.

I am also not sure, if the video would be loaded twice you would pass source={{uri: ""}} to the Video component.